# Hide/remove lines in a face

Tags: faces

How can I hide or remove these lines, but keeping it's face? Unless it's not possible yet.

EDIT: Will this also ruin beveling?
[image]

Comment: If you want to remove those edges on the front tilted face then in Vertices select mode select vertice in the center and press `X` > `Dissolve Vertices` (you can also use `Limited Dissolve`). Dissolving edges will remove faces because there isn't enough supporting geometry for it to join. Note that if those edges were changing surface of the face somehow these changes will be lost.

Answer (score 3):

You can hide edges using Bmesh, and it won't hide the faces they're attached to. Users of Sketchup might find this handy but it isn't something you'll find very much use for as your proficiency with Blender increases. But the option is there if you need it.

To run this script you would first select the edges you want to hide, then open the TextEditor window, paste this code into it and press <kbd>Run</kbd>.

This example assumes we have a mesh object in *Edit Mode*, and you have a few edges selected.

```
import bpy
import bmesh

# Get the active mesh
obj = bpy.context.edit_object
me = obj.data


# Get a BMesh representation
bm = bmesh.from_edit_mesh(me)

bm.faces.active = None

# Modify the BMesh, can do anything here...
for e in bm.edges:
    if e.select:
        e.hide = True


# Show the updates in the viewport
# and recalculate n-gon tessellation.
bmesh.update_edit_mesh(me, True)
```

to unhide the edges you press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>, while in *Edit Mode*

Comment: Says it failed to run it.

Answer (score 2):

To remove excess edges without removing faces, you can go into *edit mode*, and press <kbd>X</kbd>*>dissolve edges*, or in some cases *limited dissolve*. Keep in mind that in some cases this may result in losing some modifications to your mesh such as beveling, but won't remove any faces.

Comment: Ir removes the face though.

Comment: @Akidus I updated my answer to include another possible solution.